# Passing string and variable to php function

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables

I have a script that manage my tables and contains function to get list or to get certain data by id.
Right now one of my functions looks like this

```
//Returns a Series Object matching the given series id
public static function getById( $WHERE, $id ){
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM series $WHERE $id";
    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->execute();
    $row = $st->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    if( $row ) return new Series( $row );
}
```

But I want it to be like this

```
//Returns a Series Object matching the given series id
public static function getById( $statement ){
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM series $statement";
    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->execute();
    $row = $st->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    if( $row ) return new Series( $row );
}
```

So instead of having to do this

```
$series = Series::getById( ( string ) "WHERE id=", (int) $_POST['seriesId'] );
```

I can do this

```
$series = Series::getById( ( string ) "WHERE id=$_POST['seriesId']" );
```

Comment: You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of passing that value to your function would be like below:

```
$series = Series::getById("WHERE id=".$_POST['seriesId']);
```